# PayPal IPN OPENSSL error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, paypal

My Current PHP version is 5.3. Recently I have updated it 5.2 to 5.3

I have searched in google I can't find any solution regarding the PayPal IPN validation.

I saw my `phpinfo()` there are enabled OPenSSL but still I am getting this error message -

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/xxx/public_html/paypal_test/socketopen.php on line 5

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: Failed to enable crypto in /home/xxx/public_html/paypal_test/socketopen.php on line 5

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (Unknown error) in /home/xxx/public_html/paypal_test/socketopen.php on line 5
()
```

My Code is -

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen ( 'ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

I have used same code in different server this code is working fine. But this is not working in my own server. Please check below two screenshot-

Actual Output - 
[image]

My output - 
[image]

I read [php-paypal-error: 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926940/php-paypal-error-14077410ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-hands) But not getting any exact solution for that. Please check and let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.sandbox.paypal.com) this server only supports TLS 1.2, i.e. no TLS 1.1, TLS 1.0 or SSL 3.0.

> My Current PHP version is 5.3. Recently I have updated it 5.2 to 5.3

Given that you are using a fairly old version of PHP chances are high that you are also using an older version of OpenSSL. The necessary support for TLS 1.2 was only added with OpenSSL version 1.0.1. To find out which version you are using you might use

```
 php -r 'printf("0x%x\n", OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER);'
```

This should return at least 0x10001000 (i.e. version 1.0.1). Anything below has no support for TLS 1.2.

Comment: Here is details of my openssl version - `OpenSSL Library Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008` and 
`OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008`

Comment: `printf("0x%x\n", OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER);` I got  `0x90802f `

Comment: @Chinu: as I expected, you  are using a very old version of OpenSSL which has no support for TLS 1.2. You need to use at least version 1.0.1 instead of the old version 0.9.8 you use currently.