# HTTPS connection with Moneris servers in curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl, payment-gateway

Since today my curl request to [Moneris](https://www.moneris.com/) payment system is throwing me this error :

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 69.46.113.11...
* Connected to esqa.moneris.com (69.46.113.11) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: {my-path}/curl-ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
```

There is no news about SSL Certification modification in Moneris news feed or documentation.

So I have upgraded to PHP7 and Curl 7.43.0 and still not working.
I have also added extra ssl certificate from [curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

Why can't I connect to Moneris server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php-paypal-error: 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23\_GET\_SERVER\_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926940/php-paypal-error-14077410ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-hands)

Comment: Is cURL built with OpenSSL 1.0 or 0.9.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is back to normal without changes.

It was a Moneris sandbox outage without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926940/php-paypal-error-14077410ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-hands), even if it's for PayPal, it seems to be the same problem.

It's because they upgraded a certificate, not you. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/497843/openssl-handshake-failure) might also help to understand what's going on. Sad to say, it might just be solvable if you update one of the two endpoints. This is only a guess!

Comment: I'have seen it, but there is no information about any change in certificate or SSL config in their news feed. So I'm starting to think the problem is on my side.