# PayPal IPN not working in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, joomla3.0, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I'm brand new to setting up IPN's. I've built websites, but never a subscription site like the one I'm building now. I'd like to set up a recurring monthly subscription option and a recurring yearly subscription option.

My website is built on Joomla 3 and I'm using a plugin for the subscription module. I set up the PayPal subscription buttons just as explained in the directions, which I followed to the letter. Nevertheless, when I go to test it in the PayPal sandbox, I keep getting the same error, which says that it wasn't sent and the handshake wasn't made, and to check my settings. That's all it says. I don't know if the issue is with my site, my server or the settings I'm entering into the actual sandbox. I checked with my server and they said there's nothing wrong on their end. Do I need an SSL for the integration to work?

Please keep in mind that, while I can follow explicit directions, I'm so new at this that I don't even know how to access my 'listener,' so if you respond, please let me know where to find things, if necessary.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated - I've been at this for 12 hours now and I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Refer to the [IPN documentation from Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). Tough to help without specifics. If you can provide the specific error message, that could help. One item related to SSL/"handshake" is `TLS 1.2` requirement. While production requirement was moved to 2017, [sandbox requires it now](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US). Hth

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926940/php-paypal-error-14077410ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-hands

Comment: You can read a simple article here for ipn.  http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/08/paypal-ipn-listener-wordpress-without-using-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

This issue has two sides
1. Is Paypal IPN enabled on the sandbox account where you are trying to receive the payments
2. You would need a IPN listener script to get the IPN notifications

This process is the same for Sandbox or live mode
https://www.jotform.com/help/276-How-to-Enable-IPN-for-Paypal

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

This should help you get started